# Get correct number of lines in diff output

Tags: diff, wc

I want to get the correct number of lines in the output of diff(specifically with `-y` and `--suppress-common-lines` options). Using a simple `wc -l` does *not* work, because if both files end without a newline and their last line is different `wc -l` won't count the last line.

Is there a simple and efficient solution to avoid this?

For example, if you have files "a":

```
a
b
c
d   #no newline here
```

And "b":

```
a
b
c
D    #no newline here
```

The output is:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines a b | wc -l
0
```

Which is obviously incorrect since `diff` *does* output a line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no newline, so `wc -l` is correct. Instead, you want to count the number of start of lines. One way to do it:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines a b | grep '^' | wc -l
1
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not incorrect. A line has to be terminated by a LF character, otherwise, it's not a line (and anyway `wc -l` is documented to count newline characters, not lines).

You could pipe the output into something that adds back the missing LF character. GNU paste does it:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(printf a) <(printf b) | wc -l
0
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(printf a) <(printf b) | paste | wc -l
1
```

It might not work with other implementations of paste, but since you're using GNU specific options to `diff`, we can probably safely assume that you have GNU `paste` as well. The behavior of text utilities for non-terminated lines is unspecified by POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the man and info pages, it seems the `-l` (`--lines`) option for `wc` prints the number of newlines characters. So if a line doesn't end with a newline character, it doesn't increment the count.